# Format MSISDN number xcode IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can any one tell me how to format MSISDN number in xcode IPhone application. I have MSISDN number as "(911-111-1111)". I need to remove the bracket and "-" between numbers. How can i achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this (almost all of which can be found by quick examination of the [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) and [NSMutableString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class references).

If all you want to do is strip characters, I would probably do something like

```
NSString *newString = [oldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
```

This isn't the most efficient (or necessarily "elegant") way to do it, but it has the advantage of being the most readable.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mobile = @"(911-111-1111)";
> mobile = [mobile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
> mobile = [mobile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
> mobile = [mobile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
> mobile = [mobile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
> mobile = [mobile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@""];
> mobile = [mobile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
> ```

This will remove all the redundant characters.

Answer (score 0):

I will like to do this by

```
     NSString *string = [oString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
```

by doing this you will only get the number,which is what you need.Happy coding :)